# Mac spotlight: How does it work so quickly?

Tags: macos, caching, pdf, text, spotlight

Obviously Spotlight is a very useful resource in finding documents because it has the ability to search for text ***within*** a document as well as text in the title. This process, however, must require a large amount of processing power and time. Furthermore, a certain document, lets say a pdf is generally encrypted, and if spotlight had to decrypt every .doc or .pdf in order to search through it, this would be incredibly slow. This implies that somewhere, macs store a cached version of files such as our pdf. Does anyone know where? Or can anyone disprove this idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Spotlight has an index of the files and documents, as well as their contents. [Wikipedia has a quite a good description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29).

You can select which files or directories you want it to index in the System Preferences. It wouldn't be able to read encrypted files but they would show up as metadata (ie. the files themselves, with filename) instead if they were in the directory you saw.